# VS 2013 find and replace document.getElementById("elementId").value with $("#elementId).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to replace all

```
document.getElementById("elementId").value
```

with

```
$("#elementId").val()
```

where the ID of the element varies.

What should be the **Find what** and **Replace with** syntax?

Comment: Umm - surely exactly what you've put in the question?

Comment: What you have tried? You can use nice tool to learn and check you regexps - http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Vladimirs OP is speaking about find and replace feature embedded with visual studio IDE.. You know how to make use of regexps with that? :p

Comment: @Granga Try Notepad++ with regular expression search/replace.

Comment: @Vladimirs Bookmarked that helpful tool. I had trouble escaping some characters in the regex string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enter the "Find and replace" dialog. Then change to the "Replace in files" tab and tick the checkbox "Use regular expressions"

In the "Find what" textbox you enter:

`document\.getElementById\(\"(?<elem>\w+)\"\)\.value`

and in the "Replace with" textbox you enter:

`$("#${elem}").val()`

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Use Regular Expressions` box and search for:

`document\.getElementById\(\"(.*)\"\)\.value`

And replace this by:

`$("#$1").val()`

Answer (score -1):

In Notepad++ Input data

```
document.getElementById("elementId1").value
document.getElementById("elementId2").value
document.getElementById("elementId3").value
document.getElementById("elementId4").value
document.getElementById("elementId5").value
document.getElementById("elementId6").value
document.getElementById("elementId7").value
document.getElementById("elementId8").value
document.getElementById("elementId9").value
document.getElementById("elementId10").value
document.getElementById("elementId11").value
document.getElementById("elementId12").value
document.getElementById("elementId13").value
document.getElementById("elementId14").value
document.getElementById("elementId15").value
document.getElementById("elementId16").value
document.getElementById("elementId17").value
document.getElementById("elementId18").value
document.getElementById("elementId19").value
document.getElementById("elementId20").value
document.getElementById("elementId21").value
document.getElementById("elementId22").value
```

In Find/Replace box

```
Find what: document\.getElementById\(\"(.+)\"\)\.value
Replace with: $\("#\1"\).val\(\)
Search Mode: Regular Expression
```

Output data:

```
$("#elementId1").val()
$("#elementId2").val()
$("#elementId3").val()
$("#elementId4").val()
$("#elementId5").val()
$("#elementId6").val()
$("#elementId7").val()
$("#elementId8").val()
$("#elementId9").val()
$("#elementId10").val()
$("#elementId11").val()
$("#elementId12").val()
$("#elementId13").val()
$("#elementId14").val()
$("#elementId15").val()
$("#elementId16").val()
$("#elementId17").val()
$("#elementId18").val()
$("#elementId19").val()
$("#elementId20").val()
$("#elementId21").val()
$("#elementId22").val()
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 would not produce that output.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Input `document.getElementById("elementId1").value
document.getElementById("elementId2").value
document.getElementById("elementId3").value
document.getElementById("elementId4").value` produces `$("#elementId1").val()
$("#elementId2").val()
$("#elementId3").val()
$("#elementId4").val()` output. It's exact output in VS 2013 and in Notepad++.

Comment: No, in VS2013 the output is `$\("#\1"\).val\(\)`

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen The same output can be seen with different setting in replacement box for Visual Studio 2013 `document\.getElementById\("(.+)"\)\.value` and `$("#$1").val()`. Output results are the same in VS2013 and Notepad++.